# Need help combining data points

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a list that (right now) exists of 2 columns: t and volume, and about 80000 rows, looking like this:

```
"t" "volume"
1 20
2 25
2 40
3 23
3 34
3 45
```

I have created this list with the use of numpy's np.loadtext

What I want to do now, is add the volumes of all data points with the same t, to create a list like this, that I can graph with matplotlib:

```
"t" "volume"
1 20
2 65
3 102
```

but I'm not sure how to do this, as I'm not sure how I would explicitly state this in the code. Could anybody perhaps help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you can do it in a form of a pivot_table using the numpy sum function:

```
# Create empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['t'] = [1,2,2,3,3,3]
df['volume'] = [20,25,40,23,34,45]

#margins=True adds an extra row with the total sum of the column volume 
pd.pivot_table(df,index=["t"],aggfunc=[np.sum],margins=True)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! When I do this tho, I get three colums: `t`, `vol`, and `volume`, instead of two. both `vol` and `volume` give me the sum volumes for `t` (the thing I want), so I'm not complaining, but it just doesn't look as pretty as just 2 columns. Any idea for how to fix?

Comment: Your dataframe has two columns ('t' and 'volume'). I don't understand where the column 'vol' is. Please post sample code of what I am guessing is a different dataframe containing 3 columns. Alternatively you can take a look at pivot table documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas to do this very simply:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   t  volume
0  1      20
1  2      25
2  2      40
3  3      23
4  3      34
5  3      45

In [4]: df.groupby('t').sum()
Out[4]: 
   volume
t        
1      20
2      65
3     102
```

Comment: I get the AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'groupby'. I used `data`, where data is the list i created, and `data.groupby('t').sum()` and I have imported pandas

Comment: This code assumes that `df` is a pandas dataframe, same as you have in @xan 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could always loop through all the values inside of the 2 list and add a count to the a running tab, something like this (psuedo-code)

```
points = [0] * number_of_points
for i in range(number_of_points):
    points[t_value] += volume_value
```

this creates a list of sums, where the t-values are the list indexes, and the volume sums are the elements. Note my answer was Python 3, so you'd have to tweak it a little to make it work in Python 2